# When to call Dagger 2 inject in android component lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, dagger-2, dagger

In `which methods` of android components lifecycles should I `call dagger 2 inject`? For example, I've got:

- activity (A),
- activity nested fragment (B),
- fragment nested fragment (C).

In C I use parent component (B component), in B I also use parent component (A component). So these components should be created sequentially as described above.

My current solution is:

- onCreate,
- onViewCreated,
- onViewCreated;

but it's incorrect, because onViewCreated is called every time the fragment popped from back stack.

When I call inject in onCreate of fragments with turned-on "don't keep activities" mode, fragment nested fragments onCreate method is called before activity nested fragments onCreate, so it also doesn't work.

Comment: You should add some code how you declared your Dagger Module.

Comment: Maybe try adding a flag to check whether nested fragment's component is already initialized in your current solution?

Comment: @MuratK. Is it necessary here?

Comment: @canihazurcode It's possible, but I thought there is better way to do what I want..

Comment: I think that using single component providing all objects shared by activity, fragment and nested fragment would be a better solution. That component could be initialized independently of A, B or C lifecycles.

Comment: @canihazurcode I should disagree, because there are different level data to be injected, and some of data is unavailable in activity nested fragment, when in fragment nested fragment it appears.

Comment: @KamoSpertsian Then maybe use one global component for shared objects and make another component for each view (activity, activity nested fragment, fragment nested fragment). Then, make those specific components dependent on a global component. All shared objects would be provided by global component, and i.e. fragment nested fragment's specific objects would be provided by fragment nested fragment's own component.

Comment: @canihazurcode I do the same now, the question is in which methods of fragment lifecycle create that components. Each view component should be created once and before its child component.

Comment: @KamoSpertsian Sorry, I don't think I understand why your components depend on each other. Also, in terms of lifecycles, how do you attach child fragment to your parent fragment? If you both attach your child fragment programatically (not via xml) and inject in onCreate(), then attaching child after parent's injection can solve the problem with component not being avaliable in child's onCreate(). Can you provide a sample of code?

Comment: @canihazurcode Using ABC letters from my questions description: A contains only B, A is just frame layout, where B is set. B can have multiple C, but only one at each moment, switching them on click on button.
I'm using VIPER, so B is router for C, BComponent injects router, that's why CComponent depends on BComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is to call dagger 2 inject in `onCreate` method, but **before** calling `super.onCreate(bundle);`, because all nested fragments are created in that call. It's necessary in both activity and activity nested fragment and indifferent for fragment nested fragment.